# making permutation from two list but not using full number

Tags: haskell, permutation

I want to create a list of all possible  permutation from two list. However, I do not want to make with full length.
For example, first list is `["a", "e", "i", "o" "u"]` and second is `[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]` 
then one of the outcome would be like `[["a",1,"i",2],["u",4,"e",s].....]`

```
listsOfPossibilitiesN ::[a] -> [a]  -> [[a]]
listsOfPossibilitiesN  a b = case a of
    _ -> (listMakerN [] a b (length a) (length b) 0)


-- | list = storage, and show at the end of loop, p1h = first list, p2h = second list,
-- | count(x) = count to stop loop when the thing is fully rotated, depthCount = count to stop all loop when the depth reached 10
listMakerN :: [a] -> [a]  -> [a] -> Integer  -> Integer -> Integer -> [[a]]
listMakerN list p1h  p2h count1 count2 depthCount
    | depthCount == 10 = [list]
    | count1 == 0 = []
    | otherwise = case p1h of
                    ((x:xs)) -> (listMaker2N (list ++ [x])  xs p2h (count2 - 1) count2 (depthCount + 1)) ++ listMakerN list (xs ++ [x]) p2h (count1 - 1) count2 depthCount

listMaker2N ::  [a] -> [a]  -> [a] -> Integer -> Integer  -> Integer -> [[a]]
listMaker2N list  p1h  p2h count1 count2 depthCount
    | depthCount == 10 = [list]
    | count2 == 0 = []
    | otherwise = case p2h of
                    ((x:xs)) -> (listMakerN (list ++ [x])  p1h xs count1 (count1 ) (depthCount + 1))  ++ listMaker2N list p1h (xs ++ [x]) count1 (count2 - 1) depthCount
```

I made this function above (I am sorry for bad image. I finally could figure out how t put code in question), but it takes too long to get result.
How do i do better?(Just to remind you, I am a beginner of programming)

and, the output is:

```
> listsOfPossibilitiesN  [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10] [100,200,300,400,500,600,700,800,900,1000]
[[1,100,2,200,3,300,4,400,5,500],[1,100,2,200,3,300,4,400,5,600],[1,100,2,200,3,300,4,400,5,700],[1,100,2,200,3,300,4,400,5,800],[1,100,2,200,3,300,4,400,5,900],[1,100,2,200,3,300,4,400,5,1000],[1,100,
2,200,3,300,4,400,6,500],[1,100,2,200,3,300,4,400,6,600],[1,100,2,200,3,300,4,400,6,700],[1,100,2,200,3,300,4,400,6,800],[1,100,2,200,3,300,4,400,6,900],[1,100,2,200,3,300,4,400,6,1000],[1,100,2,200,3,
300,4,400,7,500],[1,100,2,200,3,300,4,400,7,600],..]
```

Comment: Please include the code ([edit] your question), not an *image* of code.

Comment: And *especially* not an image of code that's been downscaled so far it can't be read.

Comment: Furthermore the output can not be `[["a",1,"i",2],["u",4,"e",s].....]`, since the elements in a list in Haskell all have the *same* type.

Comment: Also, what do you mean by permutations? Would `[1,2,3,4]` be valid output? If so, just merge the lists and find the possible combinations

Answer (score 1):

Making a guess at what your current code does, here's a proposal for an algorithm:

1. nondeterministically pick a permutation of the vowels
2. assign indices to the permutation
3. use the standard `tails` trick to nondeterministically choose the appropriate number of elements from this list

In code:

```
import Data.List

choose :: Int -> [a] -> [[a]]
choose 0 xs = [[]]
choose n xs = do
    x:xs' <- tails xs
    (x:) <$> choose (n-1) xs'

assignments :: Int -> [a] -> [[(Int, a)]]
assignments n xs = do
    xs' <- permutations xs
    choose n (zip [1..] xs')
```

In ghci:

```
> mapM_ print (assignments 2 "abc")
[(1,'a'),(2,'b')]
[(1,'a'),(3,'c')]
[(2,'b'),(3,'c')]
[(1,'b'),(2,'a')]
[(1,'b'),(3,'c')]
[(2,'a'),(3,'c')]
[(1,'c'),(2,'b')]
[(1,'c'),(3,'a')]
[(2,'b'),(3,'a')]
[(1,'b'),(2,'c')]
[(1,'b'),(3,'a')]
[(2,'c'),(3,'a')]
[(1,'c'),(2,'a')]
[(1,'c'),(3,'b')]
[(2,'a'),(3,'b')]
[(1,'a'),(2,'c')]
[(1,'a'),(3,'b')]
[(2,'c'),(3,'b')]
```